# Unknown identifier when using constants C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging

When im trying to use constants in this C# application. When i run through the debugger, the constants come up as an "unknown identifier" Heres the code

```
public static class ConstsConfig
{
    public static string BASE_URL_FORMAT = "%s://%s%s";
}

public static class NetworkConfig
{
    public static string PROTOCOL = "http";
    public static string HOST = "www.example.com";
    public static string BASE_URL = "/test";
}
```

This is the line of code where its not evaluating it seems like

```
Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format(ConstsConfig.BASE_URL_FORMAT, NetworkConfig.PROTOCOL, NetworkConfig.HOST, NetworkConfig.BASE_URL)));
```

So when i step through the debugger and break on this line. If you hoever over one of the constants. It just says "Unknown identifier ConstsConfig" or "Uknown identifier NetworkConfig"

I would imagine its something small. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The debugger 'live eval' can be .. tricky. Anyway, if there is no *compile error* or *exception* then the code works, regardless of the 'live eval'.

Comment: Convention in C# is **not** to give constants uppercase names, also if these are meant to be immutable values then use either `public const String` or `public static readonly String`.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the debugger. I'd recommend just doing a clean rebuild and/or restarting VS. Your debugger hooks into your code at runtime, it can have problems correlating the IL to your source, it doesn't mean there is anything wrong with the source.

Comment: Rather than hovering, try putting the expression into the immediate window and seeing what you get.  Also try restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: Are these constants defined in the same namespace as where they are being used?  If not, add the necessary using statement at the top of the file trying to use the constants.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Ill gives some of these a try and see if i have better luck

Comment: Those are not constants.  You need to use the const keyword.  Also if you want to save some constants strings you might want to consider using the Resources to save these strings.  You can then use something like:  string s = Properties.Resources.PROTOCOL;

Answer (score 9):

There is a long-standing debugging issue in Xamarin.Android with Visual Studio related to inspecting values in static classes. Specifically, if you set a breakpoint on a line referencing a static class (or a non-static class with static members), Visual Studio may show the inspection value as "Unknown identifier: [ClassName]".

From my analysis, it turns out that the locations of class files in the project determine whether or not you'll have that issue.

**The upshot for me is that, until Xamarin fixes the bug, all static classes, and classes with static members, should be placed in the root folder of the project.** There are other file placement options, but some flat out don't work, and one requires fully qualifying your static class call with the namespace--even when not required by the compiler.

See comments in code below for full details.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;

namespace App1 {

[Activity(Label = "Unknown Identifier Test", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity {        

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.MyString);            // Unqualified
        Console.WriteLine(App1.MyClass.MyString);       // Fully Qualified with namespace

        /*
        Set a break point on the "Console.WriteLine()" lines above and you'll get the 
        "Unknown identifier: MyClass" error when trying to inspect under specific conditions...

        File Locations                                      Unqualified             Fully Qualified
        -------------------------------------------------   ---------------------   --------------------
        MainActivity.cs in root, MyClass.cs in sub-folder   "Unknown identifier"    Inspection Works
        MainActivity.cs in sub-folder, MyClass.cs in root   Inspection Works        Inspection Works
        Both in root                                        Inspection Works        Inspection Works
        Both in different sub-folders                       "Unknown identifier"    "Unknown identifier"
        Both in same sub-folder                             "Unknown identifier"    "Unknown identifier"
        */
    }
}
}
```

**MyClass.cs**

```
namespace App1 {
public static class MyClass {
    public static string MyString;
}

// The class can also be constructed this way, which results in the same findings:
//public class MyClass {
//    public static string MyString;
//}    
}
```

On 4/3/2016, I updated the associated Xamarin Bugzilla ticket with this information.  Hopefully they get this resolved soon.

Comment: Thanks for this, it is now August and bug still persists!