# Xamarin Android Resource Unknown Identifier Resource

Tags: xamarin

I downloaded the Activity Scene Transition sample application from xamarin and opened it up in Visual Studio 2015 and attempted to run the application via VS Emulator.

I'm receiving the error "Unknown identifier: Resource" at line 108 in MainActivity.cs:

```
view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
```

I haven't changed any code, I only altered marked it for deployment to execute the application in the visual studio emulator. I'm not receiving any errors when I'm in VS and I'm not getting any build errors, only when it is loaded I'm getting this error.

Is there something that I am missing ?

Comment: Check if there is `grid_item.xml` file in `Resources/layout`. Have you ever tried cleaning the project at all?

Comment: Look through your android resources.  Make sure they are set to AndroidAsset and not AndroidBundle?

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/36409069

There is a long-standing debugging issue in Xamarin.Android with Visual Studio related to inspecting values in static classes. Specifically, if you set a breakpoint on a line referencing a static class (or a non-static class with static members), Visual Studio may show the inspection value as "Unknown identifier: [ClassName]".

From my analysis, it turns out that the locations of class files in the project determine whether or not you'll have that issue.

The upshot for me is that, until Xamarin fixes the bug, all static classes, and classes with static members, should be placed in the root folder of the project. There are other file placement options, but some flat out don't work, and one requires fully qualifying your static class call with the namespace--even when not required by the compiler.

See comments in code below for full details.

MainActivity.cs

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;

namespace App1 {

[Activity(Label = "Unknown Identifier Test", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity {        

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Console.WriteLine(MyClass.MyString);            // Unqualified
        Console.WriteLine(App1.MyClass.MyString);       // Fully Qualified with namespace

        /*
        Set a break point on the "Console.WriteLine()" lines above and you'll get the 
        "Unknown identifier: MyClass" error when trying to inspect under specific conditions...

        File Locations                                      Unqualified             Fully Qualified
        -------------------------------------------------   ---------------------   --------------------
        MainActivity.cs in root, MyClass.cs in sub-folder   "Unknown identifier"    Inspection Works
        MainActivity.cs in sub-folder, MyClass.cs in root   Inspection Works        Inspection Works
        Both in root                                        Inspection Works        Inspection Works
        Both in different sub-folders                       "Unknown identifier"    "Unknown identifier"
        Both in same sub-folder                             "Unknown identifier"    "Unknown identifier"
        */
    }
}
}
```

MyClass.cs

```
namespace App1 {
public static class MyClass {
    public static string MyString;
}

// The class can also be constructed this way, which results in the same findings:
//public class MyClass {
//    public static string MyString;
//}    
}
```

On 4/3/2016, I updated the associated Xamarin Bugzilla ticket with this information. Hopefully they get this resolved soon.