# Android project using Xamarin doesn't hit break points in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

First of all this seems to be a problem multiple people have faced but I have not found a solution through their questions. So I will create another questions here.

I have an xamarin/android project in Visual Studio 2015 which deploys perfectly fine to the device but fails to hit breakpoints. The code executes right over them, including logging which prints out.

List of already attempted fixes:

- Ensure the solution mode is set to 'debug'
- Ensure the selected debugger is the xamarin debugger
- Ensure that there is an activity with the 'Mainlauncher = true' attribute
- Ensure that the android project has 'deploy' checked
- Ensure that 'use fast deploy' is NOT checked
- Ensure that developer options are set on the device
- Ensure that the path to the project contains no special characters or spaces

Each of these was attempted with a clean+rebuild of the entire solution to no avail. The break points are solid, meaning the symbols are loaded (I even checked the .pdb files).

If anyone has any idea as to what else could be the problem with the debugger seeming to set up correctly but not hit the break points I'm all ears (and eyes).

One thing unusual but I can't find any documentation on it is that the Modules window is empty, my friend who also runs the project and can debug fine has a whole set of information in this window and it could be a symptom of the issue.

Software Versions:
Visual Studio 2015: 14.0.25123 Update 2, 
Xamarin: 4.5, 
Xamarin Android: 7.3.1.2, 
Device Android: 4.4.2, 
Windows: Windows 10 Pro

Edit: added a step checked and info on modules.

Comment: Have you checked that: Settings-> Android Options -> Debugging Options -> Enable developer instrumentation (debugging and profiling)    is checked

Comment: This may be worth a look as I used to have that issue and it seemed to stop around the same time I figured out the work-around for the infamous "Unknown identifier" issue:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612645/unknown-identifier-when-using-constants-c-sharp/36409069#36409069

Comment: @AaronThompson Yes that option is already selected thanks!

Comment: @RobertBruce I'm reading it now, although not exactly related might contain info to fix the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey so the reason that this wasn't working is not clear, but I was able to find the exact setting that changed it to suddenly start working.

Android project properties -> build -> deselect Optimize code

I don't know why but instantly the project started debugging.

The issue with the modules window not showing any info still persists but I guess it doesn't actually have an impact because I can debug now.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to enable the debug mode while installing the build.

**1) Make sure to select the app type for debugging..**

[image: Selection Application type]

**2) Make sure to select the debug mode app for debugging..**

[image]

Hope above suggestion help you to enable the debug mode app which works for the break points.

Comment: Hey, I have mentioned that I selected debug on the app type. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible that your project directory name contain any special character in it.

**Change the name of project directory and try to rebuild it.**

This bug is also mentioned on bugzilla.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=39122

Comment: I just copied the code into an extremely simple path "C:/dev/gw/project.android" and yet the issue persists :C